# Facebook javascript sdk login page using ajax and php

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I tried to do facebook login without ajax as below:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '178812232292862',
  'secret' => 'c74af291ad3ab7fe02ae32b2b9332622',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php 
    if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } 
    else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I want to perform login using ajax to stop entire page loading! Following the tutorial : [facebook login using jquery](http://jennyandlih.com/loading-facebook-javascript-sdk-jquery) I modified the code as below:

Your user profile is

```
<script>
$(function() 
{
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
    {
        FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});  
    };

$('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');

$.getScript(document.location.protocol + 
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
});
</script>
```

But it does not show anything when loaded. Where is the issue, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Put the `appId` in this line

```
FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

As below and check:

```
FB.init({appId: '178812232292862', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

*Updated Code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({appId: '178812232292862', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log(response); // User Details
                });
            }
            //window.location.reload();
        });
    };

    $('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
    $.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
});
</script>
```

**[jsFiddle with different appId](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/FYFUf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks buddy! It was really silliest mistake though the problem persist as before!

Comment: Answer updated try `*Updated Code:`, If user is logged in `User Details` will show in console

Comment: before also it was showing `user details`. But after login completed it loads entire page, I want using ajax not to load entire page and show user details!

Comment: this updated code also does not shows login button if user is not logged in!

Comment: buddy if you have prior idea then you really could solve this!